# How many open connections does an REST API consumes concurrently?

Tags: mysql, rest

Let say I have a REST API for an accounting system and 10000 customers are accessing it concurrently using web and mobile clients that I have also developed. There are also other web services that access the API. I only have a single MySQL database instance for the application. I want to be enlightened about the number of MySQL connections that the application will use.

Is it n clients = 1 connection or n clients = n connections?

Please refer to the images below:

A.
 [image: Figure A]

**OR**

B.

[image: Figure B]

Which in these figures is correct? Thank you for your responses!

Comment: How do you plan to implement your API? With a framework or from scratch?

Comment: This depends on the implementation. You'd normaly use a connection pool where all connections can be reused. So you'd have like 100 clients and 10 database connections. You can verify this when using apache workbench for example to access the API, simulate clients and at the same time watch the mysql server status.

Comment: I use Slim framework for the API

Comment: I also use PDO for MySQL interaction